# Connecting to a Cisco Switch with crypto/ssh

Tags: go, ssh

I am using this code https://gist.github.com/svett/b7f56afc966a6b6ac2fc as a starting point.

Using it and pointing it to a cisco router gets me the following error message:

Failed to dial: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: no common algorithm for client to server cipher; client offered: [aes128-ctr aes192-ctr aes256-ctr aes128-gcm@openssh.com arcfour256 arcfour128], server offered: [aes128-cbc 3des-cbc aes192-cbc aes256-cbc]

After doing some reading, I learned that I could enable aes128-cbc by customizing the config:

```
// CBC mode is insecure and so is not included in the default config.
// (See http://www.isg.rhul.ac.uk/~kp/SandPfinal.pdf). If absolutely
// needed, it's possible to specify a custom Config to enable it.
```

So I added :

```
HostKeyAlgorithms: []string{"aes128cbcID"},
```

to my ssh.ClientConfig and I got a different error:

Failed to dial: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: no common algorithm for host key; client offered: [aes128cbcID], server offered: [ssh-rsa]

This basically makes me think I'm specifying the HostKeyAlgorithm when I need to specify the client to server cipher, but I cannot find my way around well enough to figure out how to do so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is to set the `Ciphers` field in the client's config. It's in the common [`ssh.Config`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Config) struct, embedded in the [`ssh.ClientConfig`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#ClientConfig)

```
sshConfig.Ciphers = []string{"aes128-cbc"}
```